# How can i set a keyboard shortcut to CTRL + S + A for a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I was trying to add a CTRL + S + A keyboard shortcut for a JMenuItem. I am using the following code

```
jMenuItem_a.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
     KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK|KeyEvent.VK_S));
```

The result I desired was CTRL + S + A, but the code turned out to be CTRL + SHIFT + A. What is the problem? Why does it convert S to Shift when I run it?

Comment: Did you try ```KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_A | KeyEvent.VK_S)```

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work! It turns out to be CTRL + SHIFT + [unknown key code]. S is converted to shift in this case too.

Comment: _The result I desired was CTRL + S + A_ Do you mean first pressing Ctrl+S and then, after releasing those keys, pressing A ? Or do you mean pressing all three keys Ctrl+S+A at the same time?

Comment: This is not supported. You can't create a KeyStroke for two characters. You can only create the KeyStroke tor two meta keys (Control or Shift or Alt) plus a single character.

Comment: I meant pressing all the three keys at the same time. But now, I understood your point.

Comment: @secdet Keycodes are not bitmasks.  That will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a shortcut of three keys is not possible unless two of them are meta keys (Control, Shift or Alt). Only One character is allowed to be used in the shortcut.